# Pandas, sum specific range of cells in a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Having the following Pandas DataFrame of **Strings**:

```
  key  0 1-9 10-18 19-27 28-36 37-45 46-54 55-63 64-72 73-81 82-90 91-99 100
1   A  1   2     1     4     1     1     1     7     1     3     1     1   1
2   B  3   1     1     1     6     1     1     1     7     1     8     1   1
3   C  1   1     2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1   1
```

I would like to get the sum of the cells of a specific row, so for example for the first row (key A) the result should be 25 (1 + 2 + 1 + 4 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 7 + 1 + 3 + 1 + 1 + 1).

How would you approach such a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If values in `key` are unique** and need select by label:

Create index by column `key` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
#select return Series
print (df.set_index('key').loc['A'])
0        1
1-9      2
10-18    1
19-27    4
28-36    1
37-45    1
46-54    1
55-63    7
64-72    1
73-81    3
82-90    1
91-99    1
100      1
Name: A, dtype: int64

out = df.set_index('key').loc['A'].sum()
```

Or create `index` first, then `sum` and last select by [`Series.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.at.html) or [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html):

```
#sum return Series
print (df.set_index('key').sum(axis=1))
key
A    25
B    33
C    14
dtype: int64

out = df.set_index('key').sum(axis=1).at['A']
out = df.set_index('key').sum(axis=1)['A']
out = df.set_index('key').sum(axis=1).loc['A']
```

Or filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) first and then `sum`:

```
#filtering create one row DataFrame
print (df[df['key'] == 'A'])
  key  0  1-9  10-18  19-27  28-36  37-45  46-54  55-63  64-72  73-81  82-90  \
1   A  1    2      1      4      1      1      1      7      1      3      1   

   91-99  100  
1      1    1  


out = df[df['key'] == 'A'].sum(axis=1).item()
```

**If values in `key` should be duplicated** and need select by label:

```
print (df)
  key  0  1-9  10-18  19-27  28-36  37-45  46-54  55-63  64-72  73-81  82-90  \
1   A  1    2      1      4      1      1      1      7      1      3      1   
2   A  3    1      1      1      6      1      1      1      7      1      8   
3   C  1    1      2      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1   

   91-99  100  
1      1    1  
2      1    1  
3      1    1
```

First is possible convert filtered values to numpy array by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and then `sum` of `2d array`:

```
out = df.set_index('key').loc['A'].values.sum()
```

Of double `sum` - first `sum` create `Series` and second `sum` return scalar:

```
out = df.set_index('key').loc['A'].sum().sum()
out = df.set_index('key').sum(axis=1).at['A'].sum()
```

**If need select by positions**:

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html), [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
out = df.set_index('key').iloc[0].sum()

out = df.set_index('key').sum(axis=1).iat[0]
out = df.set_index('key').sum(axis=1).iloc[0]
```